# Как вывести на экран значение, которое хранится в регистре ах?

Tags: ассемблер

Необходимо посчитать значение уравнения `y = (x+3*a)*(2*x-b)+d`

Код написал, вроде, правильно, осталось лишь вывести, но все время выводит или мусор или ошибку.

```
MODEL   TINY
STACK 256   
DATASEG 

a db 4
b db -2
d db 7
x db 3 



CODESEG     
start:  

mov al,x  ; 

mul a   
add ax, 3  

mov bx,ax  

mov al, 2 

mul x 
sub ax, 7 


mul bx  

add ax,7 


END  start
```

Comment: *Код написал, вроде, правильно* Сомневаюсь. Самые первые 3 команды считают не `x+3*a`, a `a*x+3`... дальше не смотрел.

Comment: Для начала вам надо перевести число в строку с той системой счисления, в которой хотите выводить. А потом выводить тем способом который больше нравится: через bios (int 10h, функция 0A или другие), прямой записью в видеопамять или функцией 9 прерывания 21h

Comment: Я вообще не вижу у вас операций вывода...